# Detect if result is 0 , -4 or something else?

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement, int

I have a method which has result at the end,I would want to detect if number is not 0 and if it's -4.
0 Means good
-4 Means something that can be solve
And anything else is bad.
Like

```
if ( Result != 0)
{
MessageBox.Show("It's bad!")
}
else if ( Result == -4)
{
Thread.Sleep(20000);
MyMethod.TryAgain();
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("It's good");
}
```

My problem is that -4 is not 0,so if i get result -4 it takes my Result != 0 method. How can I solve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you all for fast answering! I would mark everyone's answer as Solving answer if I could!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **switch** and **case**.

```
switch (Result) {
    case 0: 
        MessageBox.Show("It's good"); 
        break;
    case -4: 
        Thread.Sleep(20000);
        MyMethod.TryAgain();
        break;
    default:
        MessageBox.Show("It's bad!");
        break;
}
```

Microsoft documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just reorder your if-structure to the following:

```
if ( Result == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("It's good")
}
else if ( Result == -4)
{
    Thread.Sleep(20000);
    MyMethod.TryAgain();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("It's bad");
}
```

So your initial problem, that the `Result != 0` case is evaluated first, is gone.

Answer (score 1):

When you are building a chain of non-exclusive conditions, start with the strongest one (i.e. the most specific condition). Otherwise the code for the weaker condition will execute, blocking access to more specific ones.

In your case, `Result == -4` implies that `Result != 0`, meaning that the first condition is more specific than the second one. Hence you should check `Result == -4` before `Result != 0`. Otherwise, `Result == -4` would never be reached.

C# offers multiple ways of implementing this logic. As long as you follow a general rule of ordering your conditionals from most specific to least specific, picking a particular implementation is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change order of branches

```
if (Result == -4) \\ solve
else if (Result != 0) \\ bad
else \\ good
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, wrong code. See comment below.

```
switch(Result) {
case 0:
  MessageBox.Show("It's bad!");
  break;
case -4:
  Thread.Sleep(20000);
  MyMethod.TryAgain();
  break;
default:
  MessageBox.Show("It's good");
  break;
}
```

Comment: I think your answer got downvoted because you swapped "It's bad" and "It's good" messages (note that OP has `!=` in his code at the top).